# Oracle EXECUTE IMMEDIATE into a cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, sys-refcursor

I have a stored procedure which used the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command to execute a very long string. How do I support a very long string and return the data into a refcursor?

Comment: How long is "very long"?  More than 32K?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming that your SQL is not longer than 32K (as @Tony Andrews hinted at), you should be able to use something like this:

```
declare
   SQL_Text varchar2(32760) := 'select * from dual'; --your query goes here
   cur sys_refcursor;
begin
   open cur for SQL_Text;
end;
```

When working with Ref Cursors, `open-for` can be used directly, instead of `execute immediate`.