# Column name as variable in PL/SQL ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to have a code where i would declare a column name as variable and then use this variable to retrieve desired column from a certain table.

```
DECLARE
col_n VARCHAR (100) := 'X' ;
BEGIN
select col_n from my_table;
END;
```

What is the most easy and explicit way for that in Oracle?

Comment: This way not possible. You will have to use dynamic query.

Comment: You can try execute immediate like shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714163/oracle-execute-immediate-into-a-cursor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [dynamic sql](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm) to execute a query that you construct as a string. 
It would go something along these lines:

```
DECLARE
col_n VARCHAR (100) := 'X' ;
plsql_block VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
    plsql_block := 'select ' || col_n  || ' from my_table';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block;
END;
```

Comment: @zaratustra since there is no "selecting into" going on, that is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that, but how is it possible to `select` without `into`?

Comment: @zaratustra - the SELECT is executed but no values are returned. The alternative is to do something like `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || col_n  || ' from my_table' INTO SOME_VARIABLE`, or `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || col_n  || ' from my_table' BULK COLLECT INTO SOME_COLLECTION`. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Interesting fact, I though it was impossible to query without the `into` clause

Answer (score 3):

You can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE
  col_n VARCHAR (100) := 'X' ;
  l_cursor sys_refcursor;
  l_temp number(10); -- won't work if the col_n column has different type
BEGIN
  open l_cursor for 'select '|| col_n ||' from my_table';
  loop
    fetch l_cursor into l_temp;
    exit when l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    ...
  end loop;
END;
```

The problems is you have to know for sure the type of your column.

Actually, there is one more way to do it, if you use SQL*Plus environment:

```
SQL> select &&col_n from employees where &&col_n = 199;
Enter value for col_n: employee_id
old   1: select &&col_n from employees where &&col_n = 199
new   1: select employee_id from employees where employee_id = 199

EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
        199
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant to have a single-quote after `'select ` and before `from my_table'`.

Comment: You can retrieve column type with package DBMS_SQL, however then you have to write a couple more lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use dynamic sql/query to achieve what you are trying to do. Something like below using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Concept taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007725/pl-sql-using-a-dynamic-query-inside-a-stored-procedure).

```
DECLARE col_n VARCHAR(100) := 'X';
DECLARE sql VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
sql := 'select :p1 from my_table;'
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql USING col_n;
END;
```

Like below for SQL *Plus

```
DECLARE col_n VARCHAR(100) := 'X';
DECLARE sql VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
sql := 'select ' || col_n || ' from my_table;'
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql;
END;
```

Comment: This will result as `SELECT 'X' FROM MY_TABLE`, but does not select column 'X'

Comment: In addition, use of parameters as shown above is only valid in SQL*Plus, while the question is tagged for PL/SQL.