# concat string SQL to sql command

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, execute

```
 declare  
 @Kol as cursor
 if(len(@to_num)<>0) 
   begin
       if(len(@to_num)<18)  
        begin
            set @payam='error'              
            return
        end
        else
        begin
            if(LTRIM(RTRIM(@from_num)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@to_num))) 
                set @StrSQL = 'Mashaghel.Code='' & LTRIM(RTRIM(@to_num)) & '''
            else
            begin
                if (LTRIM(RTRIM(@StrSQL)) = '') 
                    set @StrSQL = 'Mashaghel.Code<='' & LTRIM(RTRIM(to_num)) & '''
                else
                    set @StrSQL = @StrSQL + ' AND Mashaghel.Code<='' & LTRIM(RTRIM(@to_num)) & '''
            end

        end         
   end

set @Kol=cursor for SELECT * FROM AvarezMashaghel WHERE am in (SELECT Code FROM Mashaghel Where + @StrSQL+  )
```

This code say error::

```
set @Kol=cursor for SELECT * FROM AvarezMashaghel WHERE am in (SELECT Code FROM Mashaghel Where + @StrSQL+  )
```

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

How can I add string `StrSQL` to SQL command ?

Comment: What line does the error occur on? Why did you ask the question 6 times?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045880/using-a-cursor-with-dynamic-sql-in-a-stored-procedure

Comment: @ElecticLIama:set @Kol=cursor for SELECT * FROM AvarezMashaghel WHERE am in (SELECT Code FROM Mashaghel Where + @StrSQL+  )

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is that it isn't possible to combine SQL commands with strings representing SQL commands.  This (from your code) is just not going to work.

```
 SELECT Code FROM Mashaghel Where + @StrSQL  -- won't work
```

(Your error message is telling you that the expression `+ @StrSQL` doesn't evaluate to true or false:  it evaluates to a string.)

The only way to build up an expression dynamically and then execute it is to build all of the expression dynamically, like this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(200)
SET @sql = 'SELECT Code FROM Mashaghel Where ' + @StrSQL
exec @sql
```

But I highly doubt that will work with a cursor, although I could be wrong. It's a long time since I used a cursor.

You could try something like this:

```
set @Kol=cursor for 
  SELECT * FROM AvarezMashaghel 
           WHERE ( LTRIM(RTRIM(@from_num)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@to_num))) 
             AND Mashaghel.Code= LTRIM(RTRIM(@to_num)) )
           OR    (Mashaghel.Code<=LTRIM(RTRIM(to_num)) )
```

It won't be that speedy, but it would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @StrSQL = 'Declare  users_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Code FROM Mashaghel Where ' + @StrSQL+'

exec sp_executesql  @StrSQL


FETCH NEXT FROM users_cursor
INTO ...

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
....
```