# WHILE loop in Teradata procedure

Tags: sql, while-loop, concatenation, teradata

I'm trying to write a procedure that concatenates all rows in a table in the case in which the row number is unknown.

I have this code but it is not working.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test (OUT r VARCHAR(3000))

BEGIN
DECLARE RowCnt INT;
DECLARE CurrRow INT ;
SET CurrRow = 1,
       r = 'SELECT ', 
       RowCnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM tableWithSQLStmnts
                   )    
WHILE CurrRow <= RowCnt DO
BEGIN 
           SET r = r + 
           CASE WHEN CurrRow = 1  
                THEN 'MAX( CASE Seq WHEN ' + CAST( CurrRow AS VARCHAR ) + ' 
                                 THEN SqlStmnt 
                                            ELSE SPACE(0) END ) + ' + CHAR(13) 
           WHEN i = RowCnt 
             THEN 'MAX( CASE Seq WHEN ' + CAST( CurrRow AS VARCHAR ) + ' 
                                 THEN ''  '' + SqlStmnt 
                                 ELSE SPACE(0) END ) ' + CHAR(13) 
             ELSE 'MAX( CASE Seq WHEN ' + CAST( CurrRow AS VARCHAR ) + ' 
                                 THEN ''  '' + SqlStmnt
                                 ELSE SPACE(0) END ) + ' + CHAR(13)  
           END 
           SET CurrRow = CurrRow + 1 ;
END ;
SET r = r + ' 
    FROM ( SELECT SqlStmnt, 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY TabName ORDER BY SQlStmnt )
             FROM tableWithSQLStmnts t ) D ( SqlStmnt, Seq ) 
           GROUP BY TabName;' 

END WHILE;
END

;
```

I'm getting the following errors:

- Syntax error, expected something like ';' between an integer and ','.'.
- Unexpected text 'SET'.

New code, as suggested by dnoeth.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE Test3 (IN TbName VARCHAR(256)) --, OUT r2 VARCHAR(3000))

BEGIN
DECLARE RowCnt INT;
DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE CurrRow INT;
DECLARE r VARCHAR(3000);
DECLARE r2 VARCHAR(3000);
SET CurrRow = 1;
SET r = 'SELECT ';
SET RowCnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM tableWithSQLStmnts
              WHERE tabname = :TbName
             );

WHILE CurrRow <= RowCnt DO
   BEGIN 
      SET r = r ||
   'MAX( CASE Seq WHEN ' || CAST( CurrRow AS VARCHAR(10) ) || ' 
           THEN '' , '' || SqlStmnt
           ELSE '''' END ) 
   '
      || CASE WHEN CurrRow = RowCnt 
              THEN '' 
              ELSE ' ||  '
         END;
      SET CurrRow = CurrRow + 1 ;
   END;
END WHILE;

SET r = r || ' 
    FROM ( SELECT SqlStmnt, 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY TbName ORDER BY SQlStmnt )
             FROM tableWithSQLStmnts t ) D ( SqlStmnt ) 
           GROUP BY TbName
           ;';

SET r2 = r;
CALL dbc.sysexecsql(:r);
END;
```

Now I get this error:

```
[3706] Syntax error: Column name list shorter than select list.
```

EDIT 2:

I have now rewritten it like this:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE Test3 (IN TabName VARCHAR(256))
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
DECLARE RowCnt INT;
DECLARE Seq INT;
DECLARE QRY VARCHAR(3000);
DECLARE CurrRow INT;
SET QRY= 'INSERT INTO vt21 SELECT   ';
SET CurrRow = 1;

CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt21(QRY VARCHAR(3000)) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
SET RowCnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM TestTable
              WHERE tabname = :TabName
             );
FOR CurrentRefRow AS SourceCursor CURSOR FOR   
            SELECT SqlStmnt
            FROM TestTable
            DO
WHILE CurrRow <= RowCnt 
DO
   BEGIN 
      SET QRY = QRY ||
      CASE  WHEN CurrRow=1
      THEN   'MAX( CASE Seq  WHEN ' || CAST( CurrRow AS VARCHAR(10) ) || ' 
           THEN '' , '' || SqlStmnt
           ELSE '''' END )     ' 

         WHEN CurrRow < RowCnt
         THEN ', MAX( CASE Seq WHEN ' || CAST( CurrRow AS VARCHAR(10) ) || ' 
           THEN '' , '' || SqlStmnt
           ELSE '''' END )    ' 
         WHEN CurrRow=RowCnt
      THEN   ', MAX( CASE Seq WHEN ' || CAST( CurrRow AS VARCHAR(10) ) || ' 
           THEN '' , '' || SqlStmnt
           ELSE '''' END ) '
              ELSE ' ||  '
         END;
                  SET CurrRow = CurrRow + 1 ;
         END;
         END WHILE;

SET QRY = QRY || ' 
    FROM ( SELECT SqlStmnt, Tabname,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY TabName ORDER BY SQlStmnt )
             FROM TestTable t ) D ( Seq, Tabname, SqlStmnt ) 
           GROUP BY TabName
           ;';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE QRY;
END FOR;   


 BEGIN -- return the result set
      DECLARE resultset CURSOR WITH RETURN ONLY FOR S1;
      SET QRY = 'SELECT * FROM  vt21;';
      PREPARE S1 FROM QRY;
      OPEN resultset;
   END;

DROP TABLE vt21;
END;
```

But I'm getting the following error:

CALL Failed.  [3813] The positional assignment list has too many values.

I have tried modifying it but when I delete one value than it says that column name list is longer then the select list.

Comment: Looks like a MS SQL Server SP, there's no `+` to concat strings in Teradata,  no `SPACE/CHAR`, the usage of the `OUT` parameter is wrong, lots of semicolons are missing.

Comment: @dnoeth, thanks for your help. Could you clarify why the usage of the OUT parameter is wrong and where I'm missing semicolons? I'm new to procedures and I'm having a hard time finding documentation.

Comment: According to Standard SQL an OUT-parameter can only be set, but not read (you need to declare an intermediate variable which is finally assigned to the out var).

Comment: `FROM tableWithSQLStmnts t ) D ( SqlStmnt )`:  There's `, Seq` missing. But the `sysexecsql` will fail, too, because it can't run a Select (See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28638552) I would approach a task like this modifying the Select which inserts into `tableWithSQLStmnts` to return those `column, count(*)` and run it as a cursor instead simply appending the SQL string for all columns.

Comment: @dnoeth I have now edited in that way but I'm still getting one error (or maybe more, but so far it's just showing one)

Comment: What's the data in `tableWithSQLStmnts`? Can you show some example?

Comment: @dnoeth this is an example of the SQL in that table:

SELECT 'columnname', CASE
                           WHEN SUM(CNT) IS NULL THEN 0
                           ELSE SUM(CNT)
                           END AS CntNull
                           
FROM (
SELECT 0 AS cnt 
FROM  Sometable)a  union all

The statement in the last row is different because it doesn't end with union all.

Comment: Well, this Select is useless, it will always return `0`. If you want to count NULLs have a look at my edited answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is translated to valid syntax for Teradata/Standard SQL (and a bit simplified):

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE Test (OUT r2 VARCHAR(3000))

BEGIN
DECLARE RowCnt INT;
DECLARE i INT;

DECLARE CurrRow INT;
DECLARE r VARCHAR(3000);

SET CurrRow = 1;
SET r = 'SELECT ';
SET RowCnt = (SELECT Count(*) 
              FROM tableWithSQLStmnts
             );

WHILE CurrRow <= RowCnt DO
   BEGIN 
      SET r = r ||
   'MAX( CASE Seq WHEN ' || Cast( CurrRow AS VARCHAR(10) ) || ' 
           THEN ''  '' || SqlStmnt
           ELSE '''' END )
   '
      || CASE WHEN CurrRow = RowCnt 
              THEN '' 
              ELSE ' || '
         END;
      SET CurrRow = CurrRow + 1 ;
   END;
END WHILE;

SET r = r || ' 
    FROM ( SELECT department_name--SqlStmnt, 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY TabName ORDER BY SQlStmnt )
             FROM tableWithSQLStmnts t ) D ( SqlStmnt, Seq ) 
           GROUP BY TabName
           ;';

SET r2 = r;
END
;
```

What's the content of `tableWithSQLStmnts`?

Why do you want a single line? There are simpler ways to get a kind of `LISTAGG`.

Edit:

Based on your comments (here and on Teradata's Developer Exchange) it looks like you want to apply some kind of count to every column. But then you don't need the `MAX/CASE/ROW_NUMBER`, simply concat all rows for a table and then execute it. This counts NULLs in every column of a table:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE Test3 (IN DBName VARCHAR(128),IN TabName VARCHAR(128))
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN

   DECLARE QRY VARCHAR(3000);

   CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt21(col VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET Unicode, NullCnt BIGINT) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

   SET QRY = 'INSERT INTO vt21 ';

   FOR c AS   
      SELECT DatabaseName, TableName, ColumnName, 
         Row_Number()
         Over (PARTITION BY tablename
                ORDER BY columnname) AS rn,
         Count(*)
         Over (PARTITION BY tablename) AS Cnt
      FROM dbc.ColumnsV
      WHERE DatabaseName = :DBName
        AND TableName = :TabName
   DO 
      SET QRY = QRY
        || 'SELECT ''' || c.ColumnName
        || ''', COUNT(CASE WHEN ' || c.columnname
        || ' IS NULL THEN 1 END) FROM '
        || c.DatabaseName || '.' || c.TableName
        || CASE WHEN c.rn = c.Cnt -- last row
                THEN ';' 
                ELSE ' UNION ALL ' 
           END;

   END FOR;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE QRY;

   BEGIN -- return the result set
      DECLARE resultset CURSOR WITH RETURN ONLY FOR S1;
      SET QRY = 'SELECT * FROM  vt21;';
      PREPARE S1 FROM QRY;
      OPEN resultset;
   END;

   DROP TABLE vt21;

END;

CALL Test3('dbc', 'dbcinfoV');
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer @dnoeth. When I try to call it though I get this error:
CALL Failed.  [5531] Named-list is not supported for arguments of a procedure.

tableWithSQLStmnts contains SQL statements that I got from a previous query and that I saved in a table. They are basically some select 'columnName', count(*) from Table with unions. So in that table I have a variable number of rows which depends on how many columns there are on the table I pass as a parameter.
I need a single line because I need to put all the rows with those statements into one row and then run that cose.

Comment: EDIT to the previous post. I fixed that problem I still get another error -- I will edit the main post accordingly