# Use for loop in Teradata SQL

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I would like to do this in teradata SQL/ MACRO or PROCEDURE :

```
CREATE MACRO insertloop ( val1 VARCHAR( 1000)) AS
(

 sublist_i  = ' SELECT sublist from table3  '

 FOR sublist_i in sublist :
   INSERT INTO table5 
      SELECT t.id, t.address, sum(t.amount)
      FROM table2 AS t
      WHERE 
              t.id in sublist_i
         AND  t.address = :val1
      GROUP BY t.id t.address
);
```

Explanation:

```
table3 contains list of id (by block of 1000 id)
   (12, 546, 999)
   (45,789)
   (970, 990, 123)
```

Main reason :

table2 is very huge (1 billion record).

A full join requires too much memory, we need
to create a table table3 containing disjoint list of id
and iterate on this list.

But, am not sure how to correct this MACRO to be make correct.

Comment: Can you share your actual query? I doubt that running an aggregate for each value is usefull (unless it's a high number of values and then your DBAs won't like looping). You could do a loop in a Stored Procedure, but you probably don't have rights to create one. Talk to your DBAs to get more spool space.

Comment: Join is not possible, so looping is best.

Comment: You can write a loop/cursor in Teradata Store Procedure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587919/while-loop-in-teradata-procedure