# Searching through all columns in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, null

I have a table with 300+ columns, many of these columns have no data in them. is there a query I can use to find out the names of these columns so I can remove them for the table. Also I am using a postgresql database on a redshift server if that matters

Answer (score 0):

First you get the field names

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
  AND table_name   = 'your_schema'
```

Then using a loop you create a dinamic query

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM 'your_schema'.'your_schema'
WHERE `yourfield` IS NOT NULL
HAVING count(*) = 0
```

[Using a cursor with dynamic SQL in a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045880/using-a-cursor-with-dynamic-sql-in-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: I under stand the first part and have done that, the dynamic query is were I am getting stuck. I do not know what to do beyond the first step what is the 'yourfield' coming from ?

Comment: you create a cursor, loop for the cursor, build a string `strSQL` with the query you want and `execute strSQL` I include the link with the example

Comment: ok so i am sry but it still does not make sense to me, can you please write the script in one page instead of giving links to other questions ?

Comment: sorry, but I wont write that explanation again. He already spend lot of time giving a nice explanation. If you are scare of the link, is just a link to another question in this forum

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [jsonb type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-json.html) and [functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html).

Lets say that your table declared as

```
create table t as (x int, y varchar, z numeric);
```

First of all lets convert table's rows to jsonb. It is simple:

```
select to_jsonb(t.*) from t;
```

Result (for test data)

```
         to_jsonb          
--------------------------
 {"x":1,"y":"a","z":null}
 {"x":2,"y":"b","z":null}
```

Next we will convert those result to rows like (key,value) using another json function:

```
select jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t.*)) from t;
```

Result:

```
  jsonb_each  
-------------
 (x,1)
 (y,"""a""")
 (z,null)
 (x,2)
 (y,"""b""")
 (z,null)
```

It is almost what we need. Next step:

```
select (w).key, (w).value from (select jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t.*)) as w from t) tt;
```

Result

```
 key | value 
-----+-------
 x   | 1
 y   | "a"
 z   | null
 x   | 2
 y   | "b"
 z   | null
```

Here we use `(w)` to specify that it is field instead of table.

And the last big step:

```
select 
  (w).key 
from 
  (select jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t.*)) as w from t) tt 
group by 
  (w).key 
having 
  count(*) filter (where((w).value != 'null')) = 0;
```

Result

```
 key 
-----
 z
```

Try to use the last query just replacing `t` to your table name.

---

Upd:

Also you can try use PostgreSQL statistics info:

```
analyse yourtable;

select
  pg_class.relname,
  pg_attribute.attname,
  pg_statistic.stanullfrac
from
  pg_class join
    pg_statistic on (pg_class.oid = pg_statistic.starelid) join
      pg_attribute on (pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid and pg_statistic.staattnum = pg_attribute.attnum)
where
  pg_class.relname = 'yourtable';
```

In the `stanullfrac` column you will see the relative amount of nulls for each table's column where 1 means all nuls (but I am not sure how it accurate)