# How to name a cursor dynamically in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cursor

Can anybody please tell how to declare a cursor name dynamically (fixed name + unique  name) in SQL Server?

This is to prevent the error

> 02-25-2018 10:12:01 ERROR (AdHocReportserviceImpl.java:882) : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call usp_AdHocReport(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}];
>   SQL state [34000]; error code [16916]; [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]A cursor with the name 'FetchRegion' does not exist.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]A cursor with the name 'FetchRegion' does not exist

while accessing it from multi threaded java application. I've tried adding `LOCAL` after `CURSOR` declaration but it doesn't work.

```
DECLARE FetchRegion CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT ......

OPEN FetchRegion 

FETCH NEXT FROM FetchRegion INTO @RGN

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
BEGIN
    .....
    FETCH NEXT FROM FetchRegion INTO @RGN
END 

CLOSE FetchRegion
DEALLOCATE FetchRegion
```

Comment: Is this cursor used within an stored procedure?

Comment: Yes it is used in a stored procedure which is being called from a java application.

Comment: Actually i'm using local DECLARE FetchYear CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR but its still giving doesn't exist error

Comment: Please find my structure above

Comment: Could you try with: `DECLARE FetchRegion CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FORWARD_ONLY FOR`

Comment: Please find the error:02-25-2018 10:12:01 ERROR (AdHocReportserviceImpl.java:882) : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call usp_AdHocReport(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [34000]; error code [16916]; [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]A cursor with the name 'FetchRegion' does not exist.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]A cursor with the name 'FetchRegion' does not exist.

Comment: apologies but my comment about incorrect data was wrong..the error is still there after CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FORWARD_ONLY ..please find it in my last comment

Comment: I assume you're able to execute the stored procedure on SSMS without errors

Comment: No in this case i'm not updating the records inside cursor ..but using that data to update other tables..but no updates for cursor data

Comment: yes in SSMS it's working fine..just when i'm calling it from multiple java threads then problem is occurring

Comment: if i switch to set operation instead of cursor will it work in multi-threaded environment?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think there is some undesired block.

Comment: You should avoid cursors where possible. Convert this to a set based operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sample, i used a system table to get the first 10 rows, but you can create your own cursor.

DECLARE @cursor_name AS NVARCHAR(100)

```
SET @cursor_name = 'sampleCursor' 
                   + Replace(Cast(Newid() AS VARCHAR(36)), '-', '') 

DECLARE @cursor_sql AS NVARCHAR(max) 

SET @cursor_sql = N'   DECLARE @name nvarchar(10)  DECLARE ' + @cursor_name + N' CURSOR FOR   select top 10 name from sys.all_columns OPEN ' + @cursor_name 
                  + N' FETCH NEXT FROM ' + @cursor_name 
                  + N' INTO @name WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1 BEGIN print @name FETCH NEXT FROM  ' + @cursor_name + N' INTO @name end CLOSE  ' 
                  + @cursor_name + N' DEALLOCATE  ' + @cursor_name 

PRINT @cursor_sql 

EXECUTE Sp_executesql 
  @cursor_sql
```

To the cursor name is added a guid, to guarantee that is always different.

Then a query is created and executed based on that name.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if anyone else will find this from a similar search, but we had a similar problem with duplicate cursor names and executing dynamic sql is a security nightmare.  We resolved the issue by naming the cursor with a scope-temporary prefix (#) and it seemed to resolve the issue.

```
DECLARE #iter CURSOR FOR ...

OPEN #iter
FETCH NEXT FROM #iter INTO ...

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
     ...
     FETCH NEXT FROM #iter INTO ...
END

CLOSE #iter
DEALLOCATE #iter
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it inside a dynamic sql statement. As a starting point you can check this question: [Using a cursor with dynamic SQL in a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045880/using-a-cursor-with-dynamic-sql-in-a-stored-procedure)